# VBA Force variable affectation by reference

Tags: vba, excel

So I encouter some very weird problem in VBA which I believe is a "feature" of the language.

Right now the following code generates an error of type incompatibility:

```
Sub MyFoo()

    Dim txtTest As TextBox

    Set txtTest = frmFoo.txtExistingTextBox

End Sub
```

So I've come to the conclusion that somehow VBA tries to put the string value of frmFoo.txtExistingTextBox.Value in txtTest while I strictly want to get the TextBox control object.

I know that in some languages there is a way to define if you want or not do an affectation by reference instead of value, which would solve the problem here, but I have no idea how.

I know I could simply declare txtTest as Variant but I find this very unclean :-/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conclusion is wrong I'm afraid. The mismatch occurs because Excel's object library has a Textbox object, which is not the same as the MSForms textbox used on a userform. You should be using:

```
Sub MyFoo()

    Dim txtTest As MSForms.TextBox

    Set txtTest = frmFoo.txtExistingTextBox

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know Excel had a TextBox object so everything is now pretty clear. Up you go!

Answer (score 1):

Set is always by reference. Try to declare the full type:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
  Dim control As MSForms.TextBox
  Set control = Me.TextBox1
End Sub
```

It could also be a compilation issue. In that case, try to modify the module or rename it and run the code again.

Comment: Thanks for this answer which is almost the same as Rory's. Everything is now clear, up you go aswell :)